# layoutIfNeeded is not called when reusing UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableCell that contains a UIStackView that contains several labels (Label A, Label B, Label C).

To hide Label B, the code sets the isHidden property of Label B to true for some cells.

My observation is that when the table datasource contains 25 items, and the 3rd cell has Label B hidden, when this cell is reused, the Label B remains hidden, even when the isHidden property is explicitly set to false.

The issue seems to go away when I explicitly call layoutIfNeeded() after each cell is rendered.

Has anyone faced this issue?
Xcode 8, iOS 10.1, iPhone 6

Comment: If the views dont change their sizes there is no need for layout to be called. Its not an issue.

Comment: The views do not change their sizes, but the content inside the view is. As I said, the value of LabelB.isHidden property is set conditionally, but the cell doesn't update after the isHidden property is set to true for all reused cells.

Comment: Settings `isHidden` property does not change size of anything, it just shows or hides view that is already in there with the correct layout. It's a bit difficult to know what exactly are you trying to do and where exactly lies your mistake without screenshots & code. There is definitely no issue in the layout system though.